# How can I use a pipeline Jenkins shared library to implement encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy

I'm trying to implement the `Builder` design pattern in a Jenkins pipeline shared library. Say I have the following file structure and pseudo-code (to only illustrate the concept I'm after)

```
src/com/company/builders/
                        /Builder.groovy
                        /WidgetXBuilder.groovy
                        /WidgetYBuilder.groovy
```

`Builder.groovy` has

```java
package com.company.builders

abstract class AbstractBuilder {
  protected String part0 = null
  protected String part1 = null
  protected String widget = null
}

// Implement in Widget builder classes
def buildWidget(final String p0, final String p1) {
}

// Used by any Widget concrete class
def getWidget() {
  return widget
}
```

`WidgetXBuilder.groovy` has

```java
package com.company.builders

class WidgetXBuilder extends AbstractBuilder {
}

// Overload buildWidget()
def buildWidget(final String p0, final String p1) {
  widget = p0 + p1
}
```

Similarly, `WidgetYBuilder.groovy` has

```java
package com.company.builders

class WidgetYBuilder extends AbstractBuilder {
}

// Overload buildWidget()
def buildWidget(final String p0, final String p1) {
  widget = p0 - p1
}
```

Now I simply want a client to do this. Note `my-shared-library` is a shared library that I set up in my Jenkins system configuration that has the Git repo of above file structure.

```java
@Library('my-shared-library') _
import com.company.builders.Builder
import com.company.builders.WidgetXBuilder
import com.company.builders.WidgetYBuilder

// Build WidgetX
Builder widgetx = new WidgetXBuilder()
widgetx.buildWidget("part0", "part1") // Build a WidgetX widget
widgetx.getWidget() // get the WidgetX widget

// Build WidgetY
Builder widgety = new WidgetYBuilder()
widgety.buildWidget("part0", "part1") // Build a WidgetY widget
widgety.getWidget() // get the WidgetY widget
```

Can I achieve this with shared libraries? That is, implement the concept of encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism using a shared library? How? TIA

Comment: I have some examples in my shared library https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/jenkins-std-lib but they probably are not that great. But the "ToolInstaller" is pretty neat https://github.com/DontShaveTheYak/jenkins-std-lib/tree/master/src/org/dsty/system/os/programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **very** simple on how I implemented it. It works flawlessly for my needs. The lesson I learned is that the class name **must** match the file name, and as a corollary, there can only be **one** class definition per file.

```java
File: Builder.groovy

package com.company.builders
abstract class Builder {
  def walk() {
    throw new Exception("Needs to be implemented in concrete classes")
  }

  protected Builder(final String color, final Integer numLegs) {
    this.color = color
    this.numLegs = numLegs
  }

  // Common to all widgets
  protected def changeColor() {
    // do something
  }

  // Attributes
  protected String color = null
  protected Integer numLegs = -1
  protected String shape = null
}

File: WidgetXBuilder.groovy

package com.company.builders
import com.company.builders.Builder
class WidgetXBuilder extends Builder {
  WidgetXBuilder(final String color, final Integer numLegs) {
    super(color, numLegs)
  }

  def walk() {
    changeColor()
    // Implement Widget X walk function
  }

  protected String shape = "round"
}


File: WidgetYBuilder.groovy

package com.company.builders
import com.company.builders.Builder
class WidgetYBuilder extends Builder {
  WidgetYBuilder(final String color, final Integer numLegs) {
    super(color, numLegs)
  }

  def walk() {
    changeColor()
    // Implement Widget Y walk function
  }

  protected String shape = "square"
}


Jenkinsfile

@Library('shared-library') _
import com.company.builders.WidgetXBuilder
import com.company.builders.WidgetYBuilder

node("linux") {
  def obj = new WidgetXBuilder("blue", 2)
  obj.walk() // walks like a blue widget X with 2 legs
  obj = new WidgetYBuilder("green", 4)
  obj.walk() // walks like a green widget Y with 4 legs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The structure provided in the question is correct.

With the setup provided above, it will achieve **encapsulation** through the use of an abstract base class (`AbstractBuilder`), **inheritance** by extending the base class in the widget builder classes (`WidgetXBuilder` and `WidgetYBuilder`), and **polymorphism** by overriding the `buildWidget` method in each builder class.

The only change would be to use using `def widgetx = new WidgetXBuilder()` instead of `Builder widgetx = new WidgetXBuilder()`, it allows for  flexibility and dynamic typing in Groovy.

This means that the type of the variable `widgetx` is determined by the type of the object created on the right side of the assignment (`new WidgetXBuilder()` in the code provided in your question).

Here is an example pipeline (do not need to import `com.company.builders.WidgetXBuilder` etc. explicitly in your pipeline script if you are using the shared library):

```
@Library('my-shared-library') _

def buildWidget(AbstractBuilder builder, String part0, String part1) {
  builder.buildWidget(part0, part1)
  return builder.getWidget()
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  
  stages {
    stage('Build Widgets') {
      steps {
        script {
          def widgetX = buildWidget(new com.company.builders.WidgetXBuilder(), "part0", "part1")
          echo "WidgetX: ${widgetX}"
          
          def widgetY = buildWidget(new com.company.builders.WidgetYBuilder(), "part0", "part1")
          echo "WidgetY: ${widgetY}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance is neither well-supported nor recommended for Jenkins pipeline. It may lead to runtime issues. Please refer these articles:

- https://bmuschko.com/blog/jenkins-shared-libraries/.
- https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/best-practices/inheritance-is-not-working-inside-of-my-pipelines-or-shared-libraries